# Class size in c++ based on system architecture

Tags: c++, pointers, virtual

I have created a simple class and have a data member with a virtual function. Below I have pasted the code for reference.

```
class base
{
public:
    int i;
    virtual void foo()
    {
    }

    base()
    {
        cout << "constructing a  base" << endl;
    }

    ~base()
    {
        cout << "destroying the base" << endl;        
    }
};
```

According to my understanding for above example based on architecture, on 32 bit machine the class size is 8 bytes (4 bytes for int and 4 bytes vpointer)and on 64 bit machine it is 12 bytes(4 bytes for int and 8 for vpointer). But when I run the program as 64 bit executable I get 16 bytes. I m  unable to understand where is extra 4 bytes coming from . I'm using xcode and running mac OS 10.8.

Comment: on 64-bit system, sizeof(int) should be 8

Comment: `cout << sizeof(int)` - that's how long it takes to answer your own question. programming is all about the right mindset. If you do it right, you rarely have to ask a question.

Comment: If you plan to use that as a base class please add virtual destructor

Comment: While @KarolyHorvath is talking of mindsets, take note that compilers are quite capable of optimizing things (like an unecessary vtbl pointer or a return value's copy construction) away. Assumptions on class size being X bytes or Y are usually the wrong mindset to go about C++ programming (microoptimization I'm looking at you...).

Comment: I think this is about word-alignment.  If you bung in a second int variable, I bet the size is still 16. ;)

Comment: @Debasish [eh, no?](https://blogs.oracle.com/nike/entry/ilp64_lp64_llp64)

Comment: @Karoly No, That's how you end up in the land of Undefined and Implementation defined behavior.

Comment: @rubenvb: the OP tries to check the implementation defined behavior, so it's natural to do what I told him to do. Whatever else you guys though my comment meant was the figment of your own imagination.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath your comment simply does not relate to the question. it does not matter that `sizeof(int)` results in. since it is a question of structure alignment and not of int size.

Comment: @Karoly besides what vlad says, "If you do it right, you rarely have to ask a question" is quite misleading, because you probably don't know you're doing it wrong until you ask a question...

Comment: @KarolyHorvath sizeof(int) on 64bit machine is still 4 bytes. FYI I did post this question after testing out.

Comment: @rubenvb: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Independent of `sizeof(int)` (its system dependent --> https://blogs.oracle.com/nike/entry/ilp64_lp64_llp64 (@rubenvb thanks for the link), e.g. 64bit Windows uses 4Byte for integers) the compiler may pad the classes to multiple of the largest non-struct member (in this case 8 byte because of vtable pointer).

This is to ensure that the access to members is aligned at specific addresses to increase performance and prevent misaligned data access that may cause hardware exceptions on some CPUs.